# Drop Down list in Access Report

Tags: ms-access, drop-down-menu, report

I have an access 2010 report that pulls from a query. The query has a Date, Name, and ID. What I'd like is a drop down box at the top of the report that filters on Date. So when a user selects a date, the report would refresh and show the results form the query for that date only. I can't seem to get this to work and need some direction.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What have you got against a form to select the date and run the report?

Comment: Haven't dealt with forms before. I can program a webpage no problem, but Microsoft applications are my downfall. More info please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a report with arguments.

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, _
    WindowMode, OpenArgs
```

( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238032(v=office.12).aspx )

This means that you can create a form using the MS Access form wizards and either add a combobox that shows all available dates, or just a textbox formatted to accept dates and use that as the basis of a where statement. Add a button to run the report and set the click event to something like:

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview, , _
    "MyDate=#" & Format(Me.txtDate,"yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"
```